# Create new activity and populate it with different resources

Tags: java, android, listview

Hi i am new at all this so i need your help.
Every time i click on a listView position i want to inflate an activity
and depending on its possition i whant to populate the layout with a different image and text. This is the code.. thanks for your help

```
public class WalkFragment extends Fragment {


public WalkFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

    final ArrayList<word> walk = new ArrayList<>();

    walk.add(new word("Παλιά Πόλη", "Περπάτημα", R.drawable.old_town));
    walk.add(new word("Φορτέτζα", "Περπάτημα", R.drawable.forteza));
    walk.add(new word("Παραλία", "Περπάτημα", R.drawable.paralia));
    walk.add(new word("Δημοτικός Κήπος", "Περπάτημα", R.drawable.khpos));
    walk.add(new word("Περιφεριακό", "Περπάτημα", R.drawable.periferiakos));


    final WordAdapter adapter =
            new WordAdapter(getActivity(), walk);


    final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Set a click listener to inflate and populate the place_layout and InfoActivity
    //  with a string from strings.xml and an image from drawable
    // when the list item is clicked on
    // the imageView is mImageView and textView is mTextView that i need to
    // populate each time i click on a different position in the listView
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            if (position == 0) {

                Intent infoActivity = new Intent(getContext(), InfoActivity.class);





                startActivity(infoActivity);

            } else if (position == 1) {

                Intent infoActivity = new Intent(getContext(), InfoActivity.class);


                startActivity(infoActivity);

            }


        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: Please search for your approach, you will get solution with example and explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an .xml file with an ImageView and TextView for your activity.
2. Replace everything inside your onItemClick with the following:

   ```
   Intent infoActivity = new Intent(getContext(), InfoActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("position", position);
   startActivity(infoActivity);
   ```
3. Inside onCreate() of InfoActivity add this:

   ```
   int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
   switch (position){
       case 0:
           //set resources for imageview & textview
           break;

       case 1:
           //set resources for imageview & textview
           break;

       .
       .
       .
       .


       default:
           //set resources for imageview & textview
           break;
   }
   ```

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions related to the code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this answer

```
     listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {



                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                         Intent infoActivity = new Intent(getContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                         intent.putExtra("position", position);
                         startActivity(infoActivity);

                        break;
                    case 1:
                         Intent infoActivity = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                         intent.putExtra("position", position);
                         startActivity(infoActivity);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                         Intent infoActivity = new Intent(getContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
                         intent.putExtra("position", position);
                         startActivity(infoActivity);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent infoActivity = new Intent(getContext(), FourthActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("position", position);
                        startActivity(infoActivity);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //set resources for imageview & textview
                        break;

                }

            }
        });
```